# ComboBoxItem with both Value and Text

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

My goal is to have a `ComboBox` where every drop down item has a specific text and a specific item associated with it so that, for example, if some clicks "blah" - the selected item will be 3.

As far as I can see - there's only one "Content" which represents both the Text and the Value. So how do I get both separately? (In either XAML or code, but ***without Binding***.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is highly recommenced to use binding with XAML controls, however, you can define ComboBox items in XAML by the Items property:

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
            SelectedValuePath="Tag">
     <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="1">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="2">Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="3">Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
     </ComboBox.Items>
  </ComboBox>
```

and get selected items in code:

```
 private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
     Debug.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
  }
```

Since the ComboBox item class has not a Value property, you can use the tag property to hold the corresponding value. Settings the SelectedValuePath property tells the ComboBox which property to use as Value.

Answer (score 2):

While taking advantage of Data Binding is the recommended route, you have to understand that whether or not you utilize the Data Binding Engine does not change how to properly use the `ComboBox` control.

---

The [`ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx) has an [`Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx) property, which is simply just an [`ItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcollection.aspx), which in turn is a specialized enumeration of `object`s. So, in knowing this you can add any `object` regardless of type to the collection of items.

In a typical scenario utilizing MVVM/DataBinding you would bind the `ItemsSource` to auto-generate the `Items` based upon any `IEnumerable` object; most view-models would have the following as an example:

```
public class InventoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; private set; }
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars, Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```

Notice that the collection has a bunch of `Car` objects (not `ComboBoxItem`s). Now, whether or not you populate a `ComboBox` through DataBinding or directly, it will still create an `ItemCollection`. So, if you forego the DataBinding route, how can you get a collection of `Car`s? You could create each element directly within the `ComboBox.Items` scope, or use DataBinding through a resource instead of a class (static or dynamic resource). If you don't do any DataBinding (even to a resource), you're code would look like this:

```
<ComboBox ... >
  <ComoBox.Items>
     <local:Car Brand="Ford" Model="Mustang" Id="1" />
     <local:Car Brand="Ford" Model="Fusion"  Id="2" />
     <local:Car Brand="Cadillac" Model="CTS" Id="3" />
  </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

With this in hand, the only other property you *might* need to set for the `ComboBox` is the `DisplayMemberPath` property. I say *might* because if you do not set this value, the `ComboBox` will call `ToString()` on the object to get the string version of the object, so it depends on whether or not the `Car` class has a customized `ToString()`. Now, when you listen to the `SelectionChangedEvent`, the `SelectedItem` will be a type of `Car` instead of `ComboBoxItem`. The `SelectedValuePath` can also be set to a property of `Car` and you can also get the `SelectedValue` instead of the entire `SelectedItem`, but just as before the actual underlying type would be a specific type instead of a `ComboBoxItem`.

---

**Additional Information:**

The reason why `ComboBoxItem` doesn't need a `DisplayMemberPath` to be set is because the `ToString()` member returns a formatted version of the `Content` property:

```
public partial class FrameworkElement
{
    internal virtual string GetPlainText()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Control : FrameworkElement
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string plainText = null;

        if (CheckAccess())
        {
            plainText = GetPlainText();
        }
        else
        {
            plainText = (string)Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 20), new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object o) {
                    return GetPlainText();
                }), null);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
        {
            return SR.Get(SRID.ToStringFormatString_Control, base.ToString(), plainText);
        }

        return base.ToString();
    }
}

public class ContentControl : Control
{
    internal override string GetPlainText()
    {
        return ContentObjectToString(Content);
    }

    internal static string ContentObjectToString(object content)
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            FrameworkElement feContent = content as FrameworkElement;
            if (feContent != null)
            {
                return feContent.GetPlainText();
            }

            return content.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}

public class ListBoxItem : ContentControl { }

public class ComboBoxItem : ListBoxItem { }
```

Basically, any `ContentControl` will use the `Content` object in the `ToString()` method at the end of the day. If you didn't want to create your own object, you can always use the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` object as it can store a `Key` and a `Value` (the key would be the underlying value whereas the value would be the friendly text). Of course, Mehrzad Chehraz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135214/347172) of using the `Tag` property is just as valid, since `Tag` is meant to store any arbitrary value.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
<ComboBox Height="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Books}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title">
</ComboBox>
```

where Title is the member of `Book` class `Books` - collection of `Book` objects

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to do that without binding. Just something like `<ComboBoxItem Value = "3"  Text = "blah" ...` ?